# Extend a third party dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, wrapper

I am using a 3rd party dll that is used to set up various pieces of hardware.
Each supported hardware can be set up using the same interface (let's call it IProducts).
Now, I would like to create my own, custom made "namespace" that will control some new hardware (using IProducts).
So far so good, I can do that.

Now, considering the 3rd party dll (Thirdparty.dll), is there a way I could combine my new namespace to the former?
In other words, I want to refactor the 3rd party dll so that I can access any setup (custom or not) via the same dll.

I suppose I need some sorts of wrapper? Is there a neat or usual way to do this?

Comment: You appear to be using namespace and DLL interchangably. They're different things. You can create your own code in the same namespace that the third-party DLL uses, but if you want to create a single DLL, you'd need to either rebuild it with your extra code, or use ILMerge. Until it's clear whether you're really interested in a single assembly, or multiple assemblies contributing to the same namespace, it's going to be hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks  Jon. Yes, I just want a single dll. The core dll already has multiple namespaces and I want to add my own one to it.

Comment: @stackMeUp You might want to check with a legal advisor if you are allowed to do so with the third party library you are using.

Comment: Not  concern here

Comment: Could you clarify *why* you want to modify the existing DLL rather than just supplying an extra one? It's likely to be significantly more effort - every time the DLL code changes, you'll need to rebuild it. Why not just have two different assemblies - theirs and yours?

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I am currently generating a separate dll, but considering my dll is nothing else than an extension to the source dll, I see no reason why they should be separated. An application will essentially always use the same method and property names whether it needs to set up a hardware supported by the core 3rd party dll or by mine.

Comment: "I see no reason why they should be separated" - the reason is because it's extra work for no significant benefit, and it's *ongoing* work too, as you need to update the hybrid DLL every time the original changes. I'd strongly encourage you not to do this.

Comment: Ok, but how would you do it if you did have to? :-)